# Converting DateTime of SQLServer to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am developing an app in VS2010 c# to fetch a single row data from SQLServer and insert it to MySQL.

I have fetched data and stored in particular string variable. Fetching code is as below.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (1) s_name, s_city, s_address, s_added_date, s_added_by FROM tblAQI ORDER BY s_added_date DESC", SSCon);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            s_name = (dr["s_name"].ToString());
            s_city = (dr["s_city"].ToString());
            s_address = (dr["s_address"].ToString());
            s_added_date = (dr["s_added_date"].ToString());
            s_added_by = (dr["s_added_by"].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
```

Now I have all the values but to insert datetime in MySQL need to format string in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format. To fulfil this I have code below

```
        s_added_date = s_added_date.Substring(0, s_added_date.Length - 3);
        DateTime datevalue = DateTime.Parse(s_added_date);
        string formatForMySql = datevalue.ToString("yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
```

When I get the output I am getting 2013-11-DD 12:11:SS
Not getting what's wrong here.

Please help to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change date format to [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) formats.In your case this could be helpful.

```
    // create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

**In your case:**

```
string formatForMySql = datevalue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing saving it in the format : `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` will help you

Try with following:

```
s_added_date = s_added_date.Substring(0, s_added_date.Length - 3);
        DateTime datevalue = DateTime.Parse(s_added_date);
        string formatForMySql = datevalue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
string formatForMySql = datevalue.ToString("yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
```

Should be:

```
string formatForMySql = datevalue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Explanation:**

1.there is no `DD` format => use `dd` : The day of the month, from 01 through 31.

2.`MM` in time format is The month, from 01 through 12 ,so in time format you should use `mm`

3.There is no `SS` format use `ss` for seconds from `00` to `59`

See Here for [DatFomatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)